# Bash get epoch time from custom string date

Tags: bash, macos

I have a text file with custom dates in its content, like such:

```
2018/Nov/28 file1
2019/Jan/17 file2
and so on
```

How do I translate the `2019/Jan/17` portion to an epoch format?

Comment: does it have to be shell script?

Comment: With BSD `date`,  `date -jf '%Y/%B/%d' +%s "2018/Nov/28"` will return the epoch time for midnight of the given date. How you use that will depend on what else you want to produce from the given input file.

Comment: @chepner works! Do you want to move it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With BSD `date` (that comes with macOS):

```
$ date -jf '%Y/%B/%d' +%s "2018/Nov/28"
1543442700
```

The `-j` option prevents you from actually setting your system clock; `-f` specifies the input format, and `+%s` provides the output format.

Answer (score 2):

Perl can do it:

```perl
$ cat file
2018/Nov/28 file1
2019/Jan/17 file2

$ perl -MTime::Piece -ape '$F[0] = Time::Piece->strptime($F[0], "%Y/%b/%d")->epoch; $_ = "@F\n"' file
1543363200 file1
1547683200 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise to install [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) and just use `strptime`:

```
$ strptime -i "%Y/%B/%d" -f "%s%n" '2019/Jan/17'
1547683200
```